# how to get size of arbitrary data in bytes in elixir?

Tags: elixir, byte, size

It seems like there's no easy way to get the byte size of non-string data? What's the library I should use if I want to know the byte sized of list, boolean, integer, float etc.?

Comment: What do you mean? If you refer to something like `vector::capacity()` from [tag:c++] standard library, the question would by _why_ do you need it? The answer would depend on your need because the memory is extensively shared between terms and two lists, sharing the tail, would share the memory for the tail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR** There is no such thing as “byte size of a term.”

---

Thanks to immutability, [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) and hence [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) share memory in the heap for some objects. See below for the examples.

---

Depending on what you are looking for, this answer might differ.

#### `:erlang.term_to_binary/1` + `:erlang.byte_size/1`

> `:erlang.term_to_binary/1` returns a binary data object that is the result of encoding `Term` according to the Erlang external term format.
>   `:erlang.byte_size/1` returns an integer that is the number of bytes needed to contain `Bitstring`.

```rb
> [1] |> :erlang.term_to_binary() |> :erlang.byte_size()
#⇒ 5
```

#### `:erlang.external_size/1`

> Calculates, without doing the encoding, the maximum byte size for a term encoded in the Erlang external term format.

```rb
> :erlang.external_size [1]
#⇒ 5
```

#### `:erts_debug.size/1`

> Returns the size of `Term` in actual heap words. Shared subterms are counted once. Example: `If A = [a,b], B = [A,A]` then `size(B)` returns `8`, while `flat_size(B)` returns `12`.

```rb
> :erts_debug.size [1]
#⇒ 2
```

#### *Appendix.* Memory Sharing

Consider the following example.

```rb
t1 = {1, 2}
m1 = %{a: t1}
m2 = %{a: t1}
:erts_debug.same(m1.a, m2.a)
#⇒ true
```

That said, once the memory was allocated for `t1` and `m1`, `m2` will *refer the exisiting object* and no further allocation (save for *tagged reference*) would happen.

---

The summing up, one needs to understand what *size* they are interested in.